# User lookup value is not getting populated in lead

Tags: apex

i am trying to get hierachy type field value from user object and populate it in user lookup field in lead obj when click on javascript list button. javascript is working with any issue but the field is not getting populated.Below is the java script code.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")} 

var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead)}; 
var newRecords = []; 

if (records[0] == null) 
{ 
alert("Please select at least one row"); 
} 
else 
{ 
var ids = ""; 

// querying user obj to get the hierarchy type field value.
var usrResult = sforce.connection.query("Select ISR__c from user where id = '{!$User.Id}' limit 1 "); 


for (var n=0; n<records.length; n++) { 
ids += "'"+records[n]+"'"; 
if(n != records.length-1){ 
ids += ","; 
} 
} 
// alert(ids); 
var xresult = sforce.connection.query("Select Send_to_ISR__c,Id from lead where id in ("+ ids +")"); 
var xrecords = xresult.getArray("records"); 

for (var n=0; n<xrecords.length; n++) { 
var c = new sforce.SObject("lead"); 
var xrecord = xrecords[n]; 
c.id = xrecord.Id;

if(xrecord.Send_to_ISR__c == 'false') { 
// alert("Inside False logic");

// hierarchy value is assigning to user lookup  
c.ISR__c = usrResult.getArray("records")[0].ISR__c 

c.Send_to_ISR__c = true; 
c.OwnerID= '{!$User.Id}';
c.Appointment_Time__c = null; 
 alert(c.ISR__c); 
 alert(c.OwnerID);
// alert(c.Status__c); 
newRecords.push(c); 
} 


} 
//alert(newRecords.length); 
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
alert(result);
window.location.reload(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you share your JavaScript and what the result is when you run it?

Comment: @ mike i have shared javaScript code.